# Django urls regex is not working

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

I have an issue with Django's urls.py's regex part. I want to show a page for every entry users entered.
My views.py looks like:

```
def tekent(request):
    tumentry = Entry.objects.get(id=id)

    return render_to_response("baslik/tekentry.html", locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))


def tek(request, slug):
    basliklar = Baslik.objects.filter(active=True).order_by('-updated')
    baslik = Baslik.objects.get(slug=slug)
    entryler = baslik.entry_set.all()
    form2 = EntryForm(request.POST or None)

    if form2.is_valid():
        entry = form2.save(commit=False)
        entry.baslik = baslik
        entry.user = request.user
        entry.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/entry/%s'%(entry.id))


    return render_to_response("baslik/tek.html", locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My main urls.py(not the app's) looks like this:

```
from baslik import *
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^entry/(?P<Entry.id>)/$', 'tekent', name = "tek_entry"),
)
```

and when I add an entry on web browser, it raises an error like this:

```
DoesNotExist at /baslik/entry4/
Baslik matching query does not exist.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/baslik/entry4/
Django Version: 1.6.5
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
Baslik matching query does not exist.
Exception Location: /Users/malisit/Django/sozluk/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in get, line 310
Python Executable:  /Users/malisit/Django/sozluk/bin/python
```

What should I do to fix this up? Thanks.

Comment: `r'^entry/(?P<Entry.id>)/$'` is not a valid python regex.

Comment: How should I change it to make it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems:

1. Your URL pattern is invalid, @maremare explained how to fix it.
2. The URL you are calling doesn't match your pattern. Your URL is `/baslisk/entry4/` but your pattern is `entry/`.
3. Your view method `tekent` does not take any arguments, so even if you were to fix your URL pattern, your view method would not be called.
4. You are using `locals()`. Don't do this.

Here is how to fix these, starting with your `urls.py`:

```
from baslik.views import tekent
# other imports

urlpatterns = patterns('',
  url(r'^entry/(?P<id>\d+)/$', tekent, name = "tek_entry"),
)
```

Your `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def tekent(request, id):
    tumentry = get_object_or_404(Entry, id=id)
    return render(request, "baslik/tekentry.html", {'tumentry': tumentry})

def tek(request, slug):
    baslik = get_object_or_404(Baslik, slug=slug)
    basliklar = Baslik.objects.filter(active=True).order_by('-updated')
    entryler = baslik.entry_set.all()
    form2 = EntryForm(request.POST or None)

    if form2.is_valid():
        entry = form2.save(commit=False)
        entry.baslik = baslik
        entry.user = request.user
        entry.save()

        return redirect('tek_entry', id=entry.id)

    ctx = {'form2': form2, 'baslikar': baslikar, 'entryler': entryler}

    return render(request, "baslik/tek.html", ctx)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try
`url(r'^entry/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'tekent', name = "tek_entry"),`

Why don't you use class based views?
[DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) is really handy for such things.