# Cannot get url parameter to work in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I am trying to pass a parameter through the url in Django, but nothing seems to be working.

This is my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def show_user_profile(request, user_id):
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)

    return render(request, "app/show_user_profile.html", {'user_id': user_id})
```

This is currently my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('profile/', views.profile, name='profile'),
    path(r'^show_user_profile/(?P<user_id>\w+)/$', views.show_user_profile, name="show_user_profile"),    
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

I've tried

- `http://localhost:50572/show_user_profile/aaa`
- `http://localhost:50572/show_user_profile/aaa/`
- `http://localhost:50572/show_user_profile/aaa//`
- `http://localhost:50572/show_user_profile/?user_id=aaa`

but I always get that same screen saying it can't find the url pattern.

[image]

But I've tried, all failed.

And neither does this:

```
path('show_user_profile/<int:user_id>/$', views.show_user_profile, name='show_user_profile')
```

This doesn't work either, by the way.

```
    path(r'^show_user_profile/$', views.show_user_profile, name="show_user_profile"),
```

I've looked at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24711650/django-urls-regex-is-not-working) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43470122/why-is-my-django-url-regex-not-working), and I seem to be doing everything right. What am I missing?

EDIT:

Here's my show user profile template:

```
{% extends "app/layout.html" %}

{% block content %}

{% if request.session.uid %}


<div id="profile">
   <div>
        <span id="profile_prof_pic_content">
            <img id="prof_pic" src="{{ user_data.prof_pic }}" width="100" height="100" />
        </span>
        <span>
            {{ user_data.first_name }} {{ user_data.last_name }}
        </span>
    </div>
   <div>
       {{ user_data.prof_desc }}
   </div>
</div>
{% else %}
<h2>You are not signed in. <a href="/login/">Log in</a> to access this user profile.</h2>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}

{% load static %}
<script src="{% static 'app/scripts/jquery.validate.min.js' %}"></script>
```

Comment: Can you show code written in templates?

Comment: I'm not sure if that will help -- I can't even get to the template in the first place-- but I added it to the question. Thanks for responding!

Comment: Something is wrong with port number in urls an error screenshot.

Comment: also `<int:user_id>` and `\w+` are completely incompatible

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
path(r'^show_user_profile/(?P<user_id>\w+)/$', views.show_user_profile, name="show_user_profile"),
```

Try this:

```
re_path(r'^show_user_profile/(?P<user_id>\w+)/$', views.show_user_profile, name="show_user_profile"),
```

And try to navigate on browser

Note: I have used re_path instead of path. you can check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/urls/)

Comment: Thanks for responding! I tried that and got the same thing, the debug page where it says no url matches EDIT: What I I tried was http://localhost:60951/show_profile_page/123/

Comment: Hey, I tried that and it didn't work. Specifically I tried http://localhost:60951/show_profile_page/123/ and that didn't work. I think the issue is the regex itself as ```path(r'^show_user_profile/$', views.show_user_profile, name="show_user_profile")``` also doesn't seem to make http://localhost:60951/show_profile_page/ work either. I think the issue is with the regex itself not working, even tho I've tested in a regex checker

Comment: I have updated my answer try that. this will work